# How to output a text to both terminal and install.log

Tags: terminal

I want a few of my statements from my preinstall script to be visible to the user also (not just getting logged in install.log ) when my package is installed (via terminal).

Example : when my .pkg is called via the command "sudo installer -pkg /path/to/package -target /" , I want to print out "Thanks for installing my application" in the terminal itself

Answer (score 1):

This is simple you can ua the following ways:

`command | tee output.txt`

The standard output stream will be copied to the file, it will still be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.
`command | tee -a output.txt`

The standard output stream will be copied to the file, it will still be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.

If you want any to know where I got this here is the reference:https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file/420983 @Byte Commamder.

Comment: In my preinstall script I had tried 

echo "SomeRandomComment" | tee -a /private/var/log/install.log

but when installing the package via "sudo installer -pkg /path/to/package -target /" , I am not getting the "SomeRandomComment" displayed in my terminal

Comment: Try `sudo installer -pkg /path/to/package -target / | tee /path/to/output`

Comment: I want the comment to be visible in the terminal itself.

Comment: This command should work have you tried it?

Comment: this command works for me it both logs the output to the file and visible in the terminal screen.

Comment: I did try it , the output was not printed even in the output.txt . I used echo to print out stuff.

Comment: Weird I wonder why echo works for you for me tee works completely fine can you please tell me what OS you are running.